# How to get data from not directly related tables Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have 3 classes Persona, Alumno and factura. i need to show the person fullname,  on factura using the gridview and the search function. The fullname is in Persona. Factura is only related to alumno through id_alumno and alumno is related to persona through id_persona.
i try to solved this by creating a new variable fullname and a function to get persona on class factura.

```
class Factura extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord{
     public $full_name;

}
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'factura';
}
public function rules()
{
return [
  [['id_factura_reemplazo', 'id_obra_social', 'id_alumno',], 'integer'],
  [['id_obra_social', 'id_alumno'], 'required'],
  [['fecha_factura','fullname','id_persona'], 'safe'],
];
}
public function attributeLabels()
{
return [
  'id_factura' => 'Id Factura',
  'id_factura_reemplazo' => 'Id Factura Reemplazo',
  'id_obra_social' => 'Id Obra Social',
  'id_alumno' => 'Id Alumno',
  'fullName'=>Yii::t('app', 'Nombre y Apellido'),
  ];
}
public function getIdAlumno()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Alumno::className(), ['id_alumno' => 'id_alumno']);
}
public function getIdPersona() {
   return $this->hasOne(Persona::className(), ['id_persona' => 'id_persona'])
   ->via('idAlumno');
}

public function getFullname(){
  return $this->idPersona->nombre." ".$this->idPersona->apellido;
}
```

I get and error on the return line.

PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException

Trying to get property of non-object

```
public function getFullname(){
   return $this->idPersona->nombre." ".$this->idPersona->apellido;
}
```

**1st problem Fix**

Now i get:
Invalid Call – yii\base\InvalidCallException

Setting read-only property: app\models\Facturasearch::fullName

```
 if (method_exists($this, 'get' . $name)) {
        throw new InvalidCallException('Setting read-only property: ' .       get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
    } else {
        throw new UnknownPropertyException('Setting unknown property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
    }
```

it's like it doesnt have the getter... the problem jump from the line when it tries to do $this->load($params);

```
class Facturasearch extends Factura{    
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id_factura', 'id_factura_reemplazo',  'id_alumno', 'numero'], 'integer'],
        [['id_obra_social','fecha_factura', 'observacion','id_alumno','fullName','id_persona'], 'safe'],
    ];
}

public function search($params)
{
    $query = Factura::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to check first if attribute from relation is fetched before trying to access it:

```
public function getFullname()
{
    if ($this->idPersona) {
        return $this->idPersona->nombre." ".$this->idPersona->apellido;
    }
    return null;
}
```

But this is not the problem here. Looks like the relation is not configured properly.

If the primary key in `Alumno` model table is indeed `id_alumno` and primary key in `Persona` model table is indeed `id_persona` the relation probably is set correctly but usually primary keys are named just `id` and in this case the relations should be:

```
public function getIdAlumno()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Alumno::className(), ['id' => 'id_alumno']);
}

public function getIdPersona()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Persona::className(), ['id' => 'id_persona'])->via('idAlumno');
}
```

If this is the case the above should help. If not - let me know.

Comment: the first chek did fix it, thanks, but i can't make the FacturaSearch work. The id are correct, they both are named id_persona and id_alumno. i'll add the error i get.